# Text ... could not be parsed at index n

Tags: java, apache-flink, java-time, datetime-parsing, time-format

I have the following record:

```
{"id": 2, "time": "2020-03-03T13:26:41.298"}
```

If I want to read this record with apache flink, the following error message appears:

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2020-03-03T13:26:41.298' could not be parsed at index 23
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to `DataTypes.TIMESTAMP(p)`'s implementation, it uses this [formatter](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-formats/flink-json/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/formats/json/TimeFormats.java#L38)

So you need to add a 'Z' as suffix for your timestamps (or change the datetype)

2020-03-03T13:26:41.298 should become 2020-03-03T13:26:41.298Z